# Maven release plugin with git, error if commits are pushed during process

Tags: git, maven, release, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

We use git repository and maven release plugin. In the first build step, we pull all the changes to local repository, and in the next one we run `mvn release:prepare release:perform`. `release:prepare` updates workspace, updates version in pom files, creates tag in repository, runs all the tests, builds jars etc. If it's fine, it then pushes local repository changes to remote one (updated poms and tag created).

The problem is that when somebody pushes some changes meanwhile, push from maven fails. The error message is:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://<my_repository>'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Did somebody have similar problem? How to solve it?

Comment: *“updated […] tag”* – So you want to overwrite a tag?

Comment: No no, tag is only created. I edited the question. Sorry for being not clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [pushChanges](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#pushChanges):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

... and push later

Comment: Hmm... Does it solve my problem? Maven won't complain about changes, yes, but then if there were changes, and I want to push, I need first to `pull --rebase` and push changes on top of that. Then I end up with release tag on codebase that wasn't really release, aren't I?

Comment: you will release and tag from your local version. You can merge after that.