# Maven fails to git-push build release to repository

Tags: android, git, maven, ssh-keys, maven-release-plugin

On an Android project named `foobar` I run [`mvn release:prepare`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html) which successfully builds the application and adds a  local commit to the Git repository. Then when the script tries to push to the remote repository the following error occurs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:\
        maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project foobar: \
        Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: unable to connect to :
[ERROR] : Name or service not known
```

I use public/private keys to access a local server named `mylocalserver`:

```
# ~/.ssh/config
Host mylocalserver-git
    HostName 192.168.100.100
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The Git configuration refers to the hostname and points to the repository:

```
# Git config
remote.mylocalserver.url=git@mylocalserver-git:foobar.git
```

Maven also knows about the server:

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
<scm>
    <developerConnection>
        scm:git:git://mylocalserver-git:foobar.git
    </developerConnection>
</scm>
```

The directory structure of the project is as follows:

```
├── .git
├── .settings
├── assets
├── bin
├── docs
├── gen
├── gen-external-apklibs
├── libs
├── out
├── res
├── src
├── target
├── tmp
├── .classpath
├── .gitignore
├── .project
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── ic_launcher-web.png
├── pom.xml
├── proguard.cfg
├── project.properties
├── README
```

I can use the remote server with any Git command such as `git push mylocalserver master`. Why is Maven failing though?
I can suppress the error when I [prohibit maven to `push` the release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11749285/356895):

Answer (score 1):

Check the accepted syntax for [Maven Git SCM](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html). Your:

```
scm:git:git://mylocalserver-git:foobar.git
```

should be:

```
scm:git:git://mylocalserver-git/foobar.git
```

Comment: I replaced the `:` with a `/` however the error message remains: `Provider message: The git-push command failed. Command output: fatal: unable to connect to mylocalserver-git: mylocalserver-git: Name or service not known`. Though, `ssh mylocalserver-git` works.

Comment: What's the exact `developerConnection` value you're using now? Does that hostname resolve for commands other than `ssh`?